# Datomic query performance improvements

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I have a schema that looks similar to this in a Datomic database:

```
; --- tenant
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :tenant/guid
 :db/unique             :db.unique/identity
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :tenant/name
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :tenant/taks
 :db/valueType          :db.type/ref
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

; --- task
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :task/guid
 :db/unique             :db.unique/identity
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :task/createdAt
 :db/valueType          :db.type/instant
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :task/name
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :task/subtasks
 :db/valueType          :db.type/ref
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

; --- subtask
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :subtask/guid
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db/unique             :db.unique/identity
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :subtask/type
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :subtask/startedAt
 :db/valueType          :db.type/instant
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :subtask/completedAt
 :db/valueType          :db.type/instant
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :subtask/participants
 :db/valueType          :db.type/ref
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/many
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 ; --- participant
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :participant/guid
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db/unique             :db.unique/identity
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
{:db/id                 #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident              :participant/name
 :db/valueType          :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality        :db.cardinality/one
 :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

The tasks are pretty static over time but subtasks are added and removed on average about once per 5 minutes per task. I would say that each task on average has about 40 subtasks at any given time containing (almost always but there are a few exceptions) one participant. My sole purpose of using Datomic is to be able to see how tasks have evolved over time, i.e. I'd like to see the what a task looked like at a given time. To achieve I'm currently doing something similar to this:

```
(defn find-tasks-by-tenant-at-time 
    [conn tenant-guid ^long time-epoch]
    (let [db-conn (-> conn d/db (d/as-of (Date. time-epoch)))
          task-ids (->> (d/q '[:find ?taskIds
                              :in $ ?tenantGuid
                              :where
                              [?tenantId :tenant/guid ?tenantGuid]
                              [?tenantId :tenant/tasks ?taskIds]]
                            db-conn tenant-guid)
                       vec flatten)
          task-entities (map #(d/entity db-conn %) task-ids)
          dtos (map (fn [task]
                (letfn [(participant-dto [participant]
                          {:id   (:participant/guid participant)
                           :name (:participant/name participant)})
                        (subtask-dto [subtask]
                          {:id           (:subtask/guid subtask)
                           :type         (:subtask/type subtask)
                           :participants (map participant-dto (:subtask/participants subtask))})]
                  {:id       (:task/guid task)
                   :name     (:task/name task)
                   :subtasks (map subtask-dto (:task/subtasks task))})) task-entities)]
          dtos))
```

Unfortunately this is extremely slow. It can take almost 60 seconds to return from this function if there are many tasks for a tenant (say 20) each containing roughly 40 subtasks. Am I doing something obviously wrong here? Is it possible to speed this up?

Update:
The entire dataset is roughly 2 Gb and the peer has 3.5Gb of memory (but it doesn't seem to make any difference if I decrease it to say 1.5 Gb) and the transactor has 1 Gb of memory. I'm using Datomic Free.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you had  profiled your code to find the bottlenecks. You can use the Tufte library to do this.

Comment: You may get better results by using the pull API rather than entities (you can transform the returned results afterwards)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck thanks for the tip, I'll try that and come back.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start profiling etc. you could replace

```
[:find ?taskIds ...]
```

by

```
[:find (pull ?task-entity [*]) ...]
```

to reduce the number of round-trips to the peer and thus get rid of the map statement for `task-entities`. In a second step replace `[*]` with the appropriate set of keys you really want to pull for each entity.

Comment: I've tried this and my impression is that it speeds it up a bit but it's still averaging on about 20 seconds or so. Essentially I want to pull all the keys so I don't think replacing [*] would matter much. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: sorry I don't know; indexes should be set correctly since :tenant/guid is unique. The only thing I noticed is the following typo in the schema: 
   :db/ident              :tenant/taks

Comment: I've also tried pulling specific attributes now, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Do you think it would be worth trying Datomic Pro and have SQL as backend instead of using Datomic Free?

Comment: so I guess it wasn't the schema - I don't think the Pro-version makes any difference; at least it shouldn't.

Comment: I also tried another approach by manually reading from EAVT and AEVT indexes directly but it didn't speed things up either.

Comment: sorry but I don't have any more ideas - it is strange though