# Can you eagerly load all data into memory with Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I've previously asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361183/datomic-query-performance-improvements) question on how to improve performance with Datomic but I have yet to find a good solution. One thing that struck me was that when using the Datomic Console to execute the query I got the impression that the query was MUCH faster. But I also noticed a great increase of startup time and memory consumption when using the Datomic Console compared to when I start my application standalone. This to me implies that Datomic Console pulls all data into memory before I explore the contents.

1. Am I right that this is the case?
2. If so, is this something I could do myself programmatically from a peer?
3. If (2) then how can this be done in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://docs.datomic.com/caching.html) in the Datomic Documentation, the Peer Library loads index segments in the (in-process) Object Cache when it fetches them for querying.

> 1. Am I right that this is the case?

I doubt that the Datomic Console explicitly chooses to pull all datoms into memory, but it is possible that the Datomic console eagerly traverses a large chunk of your data in order to show its dashboard.

> 2. If so, is this something I could do myself programmatically from a peer?

Well, I guess you could always artificially scan through all the segments. One easy way to do this is via the [Datoms API](http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Database.html#datoms(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)).

> 3. If (2) then how can this be done in Clojure?

```
(defn scan-whole-db [db]
  (doseq [index [:eavt :aevt :avet :vaet]]
    (dorun (seq (d/datoms db index)))))
```

That all being said, I'm not sure at all you should expect performance improvements from this strategy. Your Object Cache had better be large enough!